# Changing the entire permalink

Tags: permalinks, phpmyadmin

I have a plugin that creates a custom post. I want to change the permalink from: `https://[site name]/lesson/lesson-1/` To: `https://[site name]/learn/lesson1.php`

Through the wp admin interface, I can only change the slug as seen below.

[image]

There is a plugin that will allow such functionality: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

But I would prefer to do this manually myself. How can I safely change the entire permalink to something else?

Comment: Your plugin creates a *post* or a custom post *type*?

Comment: I don't own the plugin. It is lifterlms. The type is *lesson* according to phpmyadmin. I assume that means that it is a custom post type

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have permalink ending in `.php` while you have pretty link enabled...

Comment: In that case, how do I disable *pretty link*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the case where you want to change "lesson" to "learn", there's actually a "rewrite" option you could use, if you were the one [registering the new post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). Since you are not, however, you have to be a little bit more crafty.

Thankfully, WP gives you a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) to modify the post registration arguments before it registers it, so you can modify your plugin's implementation:

```
function change_lesson_rewrite_rule($args, $post_type) {
    if(isset($args['rewrite']) && is_array($args['rewrite'])) $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'learn';
    else $args['rewrite'] = array('slug' => 'learn');
    return $args;
}
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'change_lesson_rewrite_rule', 1000, 2);
```

I've given your filter a high priority (1000) to make sure it's one of the last ones to affect the arguments array.

As for changing the whole domain to another, that would not work - and wouldn't be a good idea... Rewrites only work for the path part of a URL. The domain is your site's address, you can't change that - unless you want people to end up on a totally different site! ;)

**UPDATE**

Ok, so it seems you instead have physical pages (static or php) that you would like to show visitors, that are not served through WordPress. In this case, the rewrite rules in .htaccess already allow this. All you need is to place your files in your root folder. In your case:

```
...
wp-config.php
wp-content
...
learn/ <---- create this folder
    lesson1.php <---- place your files here
```

This will allow people to view the URL https://[site name]/learn/lesson1.php

**UPDATE 2**

Based on your latest comments, you have two options: you can do a Apache rewrite or you can use WordPress' [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook. The Apache solution might run a bit faster, but both versions will work:

**Apache rewrite option**

In your site's .htaccess file, you could add this block (I'd add it before WP's block)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^lesson/(.*)$ /learn/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

**template_redirect option**

Alternatively, you can do the redirect from within WordPress' code. In your theme functions.php file, you could add:

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    if(preg_match('/\/lesson\/(.*?)$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/learn/'.$matches[1]));
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I created some pages myself and uploaded them to the directory structure through File Manager in cPanel. These pages, which I created are not in the database, and I want the user to go directly there when they click on a lesson. It is almost like sending them to a different website.

Comment: Ah ok - so for physical pages outside of WP, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes. I placed them in the root folder and I can access them easily. I want the user to go to this page https://[site name]/learn/lesson1.php automatically when they click on a lesson. I don't want to do this with regular links. I just want to change the permalink. Right now I am using iFrames but it would be nice to have a more elegant solution.

Comment: All righty - I've updated my answer.